# How to copy and filtered an ImmutableList<? extends MyObject> in Java

Tags: java, list, parameterized-class

Basically, I want to have

```
public ImmutableList<? extends MyObject> getFilteredList(ImmutableList<? extends MyObject> initial) {
    ArrayList<? extends MyObject> newList = new ArrayList<? extends MyObject>();
    for (MyObject temp: initial) {
        if (doesFulfillCriteria(temp)) newList.add(temp);
    }
    return newList
}
```

But the line

```
newList.add(temp);
```

gives me an error saying that newList expects `<? extends MyObject>`, found MyObject instead.

Apparently I can't do something like

```
for (? extends MyObject temp: initial) {
```

either.

Please help?

Comment: Note that with your current implementation, the type of `ImmutableList` returned by the method does not necessarily have to match the type of the `ImmutableList` passed as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that multiple `?` wildcards are not guaranteed to represent the same type.  Another is that wildcards aren't allowed when instantiating an object, such as `new ArrayList<? extends MyObject>();`.

The solution here is to make this method generic with an upperbound, so we can refer to the same `T` throughout the method:

```
public <T extends MyObject> ImmutableList<T> getFilteredList(ImmutableList<T> initial) {
    ArrayList<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T temp : initial) {
        if (doesFulfillCriteria(temp)) newList.add(temp);
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Additionally, you may need to change the return type to `ArrayList` if you're going to return an `ArrayList`.

Comment: +1. This allows getting back a List<Foo> when filtering a List<Foo>, and a List<Bar> when filtering a List<Bar>, which is not the case of the other answer.

Comment: @Downvoter Please explain what's wrong or how it can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use the following code:

```
public ImmutableList<? extends MyObject> getFilteredList(ImmutableList<? extends   MyObject> initial) {
    List<MyObject> newList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    for (MyObject temp: initial) {
        if (doesFulfillCriteria(temp)) newList.add(temp);
    }
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(newList);
}
```

If you know that the parameter extends MyObject, then you can use MyObject directly as all parameters will extend it.

There were few problems with your code:

- you can not instantiate an array with wildcard ?, it has to be a concrete type or a generic
- you can not return array list, you need to create a immutable list

You could also use more functional approach:

```
public ImmutableList<? extends MyObject> getFilteredList(ImmutableList<? extends   MyObject> initial) {

    return ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.filter(initial, new Predicate<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(MyObject o) {
            return doesFulfillCriteria(o);
        }}));
}
```